# Update Employee Name Task Field With Employee Name From List Data

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow, tasks, workflow-tasks-list

I have a list that a user fills in their travel data. Once this data is submitted a 2013 Workflow is kicked off that includes a task for each manager. Management wants the submitter's name to appear on the task list so they can approve numerous tasks at once once they click on the emailed link.

I could put the name in the title field but that makes it extremely long with the other list data.

I added a workflow line that updates the field but it will only update the field once that task has been completed, which is not helpful.

I tried a parallel task with the task and update together but neither run then.

Is there a way to get the submitter's name to show up on the task list?
[image: Missing Traveler]

Comment: Have you tried with giving condition on parallel block?. Also if possible, pls share the workflow content for more information.